# How to write MDB content to INI files in Delphi 7?

Tags: loops, delphi, delphi-7, ini

There is a table entry for mdb. And the table has 18 columns and 10 rows.
I want to write the contents of the table in the ini file.
Is there a way?

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ini : TIniFile;
  i : Integer;
  sTableInfo : String;

begin

  Adotable1.First;
  ini := TIniFile.Create('C:\Users\win10_pro\Desktop\test.ini');
  sTableInfo := Adotable1['name'] + '  '  +Adotable1['capital']+ '  ' +   Adotable1['continent'];
  
  try
  for i := 0 to adotable1.RecordCount - 1 do
     begin
        ini.WriteString('Name', 'test1', sTableInfo );
      end;
        ShowMessage('INI file create');
      end;
  finally
    ini.Free;
  end;
```

This way, only one item goes in, and I want all items to go in. This way, only one item goes in, and I want all items to go in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have no idea why you want to do this, since you have a perfectly good database that is already storing the data. However, this should do what you want (untested). Note I also had to change the code that writes to the INI file so that the key changes with every pass, or only one value is written.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ini : TIniFile;
  keyNo: Integer;
  sTableInfo : String;
begin
  Adotable1.First;
  ini := TIniFile.Create('C:\Users\win10_pro\Desktop\test.ini');
  keyNo := 1;
  try
     while not adotable1.Eof do
     begin
       sTableInfo := Adotable1['name'] + '  '  +Adotable1['capital']+ '  ' +   Adotable1['continent'];

       ini.WriteString('Name', 'test' + IntToStr(keyNo), sTableInfo );
       Inc(keyNo);
       adoTable1.Next;
     end;
     ShowMessage('INI file created');
  finally
    ini.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindness and reply. However, after testing your code, only the last item, not all the values of the item, is written in the INI.

Comment: It's because you're using the same section and key in your call to `Ini.WriteString`. Give me a minute to fix it - I missed that when I rewrote your code.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Ken ! You are the god of Delphi. Thank you !